# Selenium (Python) not finding dynamically loaded JavaScript table after automated login occurs

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Im using Selenium with Python3 on a Service Now Website.

So the process is as follows: selenium loads up the ServiceNow URL and then I use sendKeys to automate typing in of username and password, then the page is loaded which has a table of incidents I need to extract. Unfortunately I have to login in every single time because of the group policy I have.

This works up until I have to find the dynamically rendered Javascript table with data and I can't for the life of me seem to find it. I even tried to put a sleep in there for 15 seconds to allow it to load.

I also double checked the XPaths and Id / Class names and they match up. When I print query.page_source I don't see anything rendered by JS.

I've used beautiful soup too but that also doesn't work.

Any ideas?

```
from time import sleep
from collections import deque
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select # for <SELECT> HTML form
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

query = webdriver.Firefox()

get_query = query.get("SERVICENOW URL")

query.implicitly_wait(10)

login_username = query.find_element_by_id('username')

login_password = query.find_element_by_id('password')

login_button = query.find_element_by_id('signOnButton')

username = "myUsername"
password = "myPassword"

login_username.send_keys(username)
login_password.send_keys(password)
login_button.click()

sleep(10)

incidentTableData = []

print(query.page_source)

// *** THESE ALL FAIL AND RETURN NONE ***
print(query.find_elements())
tableById = query.find_element_by_id('service-now-table-id')
tableByXPath = query.find_element_by_xpath('service-now-xpath')
tableByClass = query.find_element_by_id('service-now-table-class')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a `dynamically rendered Javascript table`, I would suggest you to implement explicit wait in your code.

so instead of this  :

```
tableById = query.find_element_by_id('service-now-table-id')
tableByXPath = query.find_element_by_xpath('service-now-xpath')
tableByClass = query.find_element_by_id('service-now-table-class')
```

re-write these lines like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(query, 10)
service_now_with_id = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "service-now-table-id")))
service_now_with_xpath = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "service-now-xpath")))
service_now_with_class = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "service-now-table-class")))
```

You are gonna need to use the below **imports**  :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as E
```

PS :- `service_now_with_id`, `service_now_with_xpath`, `service_now_with_class`, these are web elements returned by explicit waits. you may wanna have to interact with them as per your requirement meaning, clicking on it or sending keys or whatever.